# How to install 32bit SDL on 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: apt

I have an application that is dependent ia32-libs. But now that this package has been deprecated, it seems like I'll have to install everything by hand...

It seems that that I can install it like this: `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev:i386`, but apt-get wants to remove some libraries, namely:

`bbswitch-source libasan0:i386 libasound2-dev libatomic1:i386
  libcloog-isl4:i386 libdbus-1-dev libgcc-4.8-dev:i386 libglew1.8
  libgmp10:i386 libgomp1:i386 libisl10:i386 libitm1:i386 libjbig-dev
  libjpeg-dev libkms1 liblzma-dev libmad0-dev libmikmod2 libmikmod2-dev
  libmpc3:i386 libmpfr4:i386 libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libquadmath0:i386
  libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libtiff5-dev libtiffxx5
  libwebp-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxdamage-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxxf86vm-dev module-assistant nvidia-settings-304-updates primus-libs
  primus-libs:i386 primus-libs-ia32:i386 socat`

... And this just won't do because I'll to re-install Bumblebee. :|
Am I doing something wrong?~